# Angular9 router.navigate

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, router

If the website was enabled on the old browser, my goal is to redirect the page to one with information about it. For this I use the ngx-device-detector package. And for redirect I am using this.router.navigate which is not working. Does anyone know why url is not replaced? Even though the condition is met, nothing happens.

```
 if(this.browserName === 'Chrome' && this.browserVersion < 83) {
      this.router.navigate(['/pages/unsupported-browsers-component'])
    }
  }
```

This is part of routing module file

```
    {
      path: 'pages/unsupported-browsers-component',
      component: UnsupportedBrowsersComponent,
    },
```

Comment: Can you show the Routing Module (s) ?

Comment: App / Feature Modules as well ?

Comment: is your route '/pages/unsupported-browsers-component' relative or absolute ??

Comment: can you share your routing file also, I think there is some issue with the path you have added in navigate function because you have used navigate and you are passing path, you should either use navigateurl or pass path name to navigate refer link https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate

Comment: so it could be with the slash in your path you don't have / and you are using it in navigate method. try removing it

Comment: @Vinita thanks that was it, i saw this bugs ;)

Comment: great.. your welcome.. adding it as an answer please accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Navigate function needs to have a pathname without a slash at the start, or you can simply use the path too with slash giving the absolute or relative URL to your component in the NaviagteUrl method.
Refer link: [angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate](http://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate)